# Removing the first element in an array without using array methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, queue

So I have homework that requires me to dequeue from an array like so:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3]
```

My only problem is that I'm restricted in using any array method except for the .length method.

I have tried using the delete to remove the first element but I know it doesn't adjust the array and reflects undefined for the first element:

```
function dequeue(){
  delete arr[0];
  console.log(arr)
}
```

Any help or advice on how to do it is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming, you can still use assigment with index, you could copy all items one index before and decrement the length of the array.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3];

for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) array[i - 1] = array[i];

array.length--;

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If **.map** is allowed to use in your case.

```
array = array.map((elm,index,arr) => arr[index+1]);
array.length--;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Destructuring assignment.
try this out:

```
const [firstElement, ...restOfTheArray] = yourArray;
```

`restOfTheArray` is the same array with the first element removed.

Answer (score -1):

For left shift:

```
function shiftArrLeft(arr) {
        let a = arr[0];
        let newArr = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {
            newArr[i - 1] = arr[i];
        }
        newArr[newArr.length] = a;
        console.log(newArr);
    }
```

For right shift:

```
function shiftArrRight(arr) {
    let a = arr[arr.length - 1];
    let newArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        newArr[i + 1] = arr[i];
    }
    newArr[0] = a;
    console.log(newArr);
}
```

Comment: This does not remove the first/last element as requested.